# Ratings and Review Index - whats a simple formula to calculate

Tags: php, rating, review

We have a site where users can rate and review entries. A review is basically a rating with no text content and a rating is marked as a number 1 to 5 on how well a user ranks a listing.

The issue we get comes with sorting entries based on ratings, technically listings that have more ratings and a greater average of ratings should rank higher and be sorted accordingly. For this I'm thinking of added a rating index field to our listings which is updated whenever a rating/review is made.

What I'm stuck with is how to calculate the rating here. For example an entry with 5 ratings and 2 reviews should not be higher than an entry with 5 reviews and two ratings. Likewise if a rating is made by a user who has made more than x number of reviews his rating carries more weight.

Basically the rating index here is a value that is caculated on the basis of Sum of the value allocated to ratings made.

A review will be of a higher value than a rating, and a review made by a user who has more than x reviews written will definitely have a higher value.

What I'm stuck on is figuring out an effective formula so we can caluclate a rating index that doesn't look haphazard when sorting and still make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just weight ratings and reviews with users numbers of ratings and review?

Users may be allocated more weight each time they post more than 5, 10, 20, 50, etc, reviews, or you could weight for each and every review...

Your database should be able to maintain a weight column that is kept updated every time a user adds something. Then, how much you weight things is something subjective and dependant and other things like how much a lambda user is trustworthy compared to old active ones, as well as how much traffic you get...